# warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers, what should i use instead?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I will simplify the problem to be more concrete.
Compiling my c++ program with g++ and the -pedantic argument like this:

> g++ -Wall -pedantic main.cpp

Gives me the following warning:

> warning: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]

This is what I am trying to implement:

```
typedef enum {
  ARG_HELP_LONG,
  ARG_HELP_SHORT,
} arg_t;

static const char *valid_args[] = {[ARG_HELP_LONG] = "--help",
                                   [ARG_HELP_SHORT] = "-h",
}
```

So that I can compare it to something else:

```
 if (strcmp(argv[i], valid_args[ARG_HELP_LONG]) == 0 || strcmp(argv[i], valid_args[ARG_HELP_SHORT]) == 0) {
    do something..
}
```

What should I use instead?

Also I get a warning telling me that I am not using valid_args, but I do use it. Is there any way of fixing this? Is it related to the above warning?

Comment: The error message gave you a term to search. Searching "C++ designated initializers" pulls up [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) page, where you can see the syntax and required C++ standard version.

Comment: whats wrong with just removing the designated initializer? `static const char *valid_args[] = {"--help", "-h"}` ?

Comment: @sweenish "[...] , and designated initialization of arrays are all supported in the C programming language, but are not allowed in C++. "

Comment: Meh, I guess I rushed into this one. Maybe I should have just gone with my "try writing C++" snark. Because this is C. Why not just use a C compiler?

Comment: SNARK. The big-bad of the next TRON film...

Comment: Although it may be overkill for a map with only two entries I suggest considering `std::map<arg_t, std::string> valid_args{{ARG_HELP_LONG, "--help"}, {ARG_HELP_SHORT, "-h"}}`.     It would be more useful if you need a map with a larger number of entries.   Bear in mind that a `map`s `operator[]()` will insert an element into the map if the key doesn't exist - but you can use the `.at()` member function (which will throw an exception if given a non-existent key) instead - which I would argue is preferable to using an array (which will give undefined behaviour for a non-existent index).

Answer (score 2):

Just do not use the designated initialization of the array:

```
static const char *valid_args[] = {"--help","-h"};
```

Indices of the two elements are `0` and `1`, respectively. The same as with the designated initializers, because the value of `ARG_HELP_LONG` and `ARG_HELP_SHORT` are `0` and `1`, respectively.

C++ has designated initializers since C++20, though (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)):

> Note: out-of-order designated initialization, nested designated
> initialization, mixing of designated initializers and regular
> initializers, and designated initialization of arrays are all
> supported in the C programming language, but are not allowed in C++.